# Dynamically loading child components in parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am a beginner in Vue.js so please bear with me. I created two child components and one parent component. I am able to load both the components in the parent components. Now, one of my child component should load in the parent component by default. It will have a link, and when clicked, it should load the other child component within the same parent component, by passing and ID value from itself to the loading component. Below is my code.

**Parent component (App.vue):**

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="main-body">
        <component v-bind:is="currentComp">
        </component>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import HomeContent from './components/HomeContent.vue';
import DetailContent from './components/DetailContent.vue';
import { changeRoute } from './main.js';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      currentComp: 'HomeContent'
    };
  },
  components: {
    HomeContent, //this is the default child component
    DetailContent, //this is the other child component which should get loaded dynamically
  },
  created() {
      changeRoute.$on('switchComp', comp => {
           this.currentComp = comp;
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

**Default child component (HomeContent.vue):**

```
<template>
    <div>
        This is Default child component
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" @click="switchComponent('DetailContent')">Click to load the other child dynamically</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { changeRoute } from '../main.js';

export default {
  name: 'HomeContent',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  methods: {
    switchComponent(comp) {
      changeRoute.$emit('switchComp', comp);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**The other child component (DetailContent):**

```
<template>
    <div>
        This is the other loaded child component.
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'DetailContent',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  mounted(){
      alert('mount ok');
  }
}
</script>
```

With the above approach `DetailContent` get loaded on click of a link from the `HomeContent`. Now, how can pass some data (e.g. ID = 1) from `HomeContent` to `DetailContent`. Any help with this please?

Comment: have you ever used the vue-router? this is what it is for

Comment: @DanOswalt Just looking into it.

Comment: @DanOswalt is right. What you specifically wanted to use for this is `vue-router`

Comment: @SouvikGhosh, as others suggested, you should use `vue-router` or if that's too much for simple task, consider using `dymanic-component`.

Comment: @HarshalPatil I have edited my post with some approach I got. Now I need to pass data.

Comment: @DanOswalt Please check my updated post. I did some work around but need to pass some data now.

Comment: you can use `v-bind="{prop: value}"` in the `<component>` tag to dynamically pass props to it.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag Thanks. Took a lot of time but I figured out eventually. This is how I did- `<component v-bind:<prop_name_in_childcomponent>="dataValue" v-bind:is="currentComp"></component>`.